# Pointer shape in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to configure when the pointer changes from arrow to hand? I'm talking about the interface, not web pages. For example, when hovering over Firebug's icon, the pointer turns into a hand but on greasemonkey, stylish and gmail manager it stays arrow shaped.

I'd like it to turn into hand on all active places:
- addon mini-icons
- tabs
- bookmark buttons in the personal bookmark toolbar

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following in your userChrome.css file:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

toolbarbutton,
.tabbrowser-tabs *,
statusbarpanel image,
.statusbarpanel-menu-iconic {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

You can find your userChrome.css file at `YourProfileDir/chrome/userChrome.css` where YourProfileDir means:

- `%APPDATA%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/[profile name]/` for Windows
- `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[random string].default/` for Mac OS X
- `~/.mozilla/[Linux Login Name]/[random string].slt/` for Linux

If the file doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: Perfect for toolbar and tabs, is there a selector for addon icons (those on bottom right) too? Thanks

Comment: Yep, I've edited the answer to include those. I used the DOM Inspector extension to figure out the selectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. One last thing, is there a way to tell Firefox to reload `userChrome.css` other than closing and restarting it?

Comment: Not that I know of but do tell me if you find a way!

Comment: @kemp, if you have stylish install just add it as a stylish script. No need to touch userChrome.css